# matching string on the begining of the line with ash

Tags: busybox, ash, expr

I'm trying to match a string on the beginning of the line

```
a.z //match
# a.z
bc.x //match
 #bc.x
c.z
 bc.z //match
```

here is my code:

```
   while read p; do
      if [ $(expr match "$p" '^a\..*|^bc\..*') ];
      then
         echo $p
      fi
   done <file.txt
```

i get this error:

> expr: warning: '^a..*|^bc..*: using '^' as the first character
> of a basic regular expression is not portable; it is ignored

What is the problem?

Comment: `expr` is from 80's. Use modern bash :)

Comment: its busybox OS.

Comment: So use `grep` or `awk`

Comment: No idea why it is considered "not portable", but `info expr` (the GNU version) states that _"The arguments are converted to strings and the second is considered to be a (basic, a la GNU ‘grep’) regular expression, with a ‘^’ implicitly prepended"_. So your `^` anchoring is useless. And if you want alternation, since this is BRE, you might have to use `\|` instead of `|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do, using `awk`:

```
awk '/^a\..*|^bc\..*/' file
```

---

`expr` is a program used in **ancient shell code to do math**.
This syntax has been obsolete for a few decades.